# I cannot link my react front and my back nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

i'm trying to authenticate myself in my node js react app.
this is my code and my error.

[Authentication Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cguh.png)

[Authentication Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DL4J.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. It can't be copied, indexed and links to the images may become unavailable. Instead copy the code into a code block or use the snippet editor. Also questions like "why isn't this code working" are not specific enough. Be more precise and describe the concrete problem so that others that encounter the same problem can profit from the answers too.

Answer (score -1):

You should allow CORS access, for this you should use [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library, then use it like this in your app.js file:

```
const cors = require("cors");

    app.use(cors({
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
        credentials: true // enable set cookie
    }));
```

But please update your question and post all your code and error as well.

Answer (score -1):

You defined the CORS Policy, with that you have define the library like

```js
const cors=require('cors');
```

Link: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html